# Angular using ng-bind-html and ng-model together in select dropdown?

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

Is it possible to use ng-bind-html and ng-model together on the same select dropdown? In my application I have a select dropdown that gets populated with ng-bind-html (which is working fine) but when I try to bind the value of the dropdown to the $scope with ng-model, it isn't updating the scope with the value of the dropdown, it just stays the same as the original declaration in my controller. Here is what it looks like:

```
<select id="newNumOfPlayers" ng-bind-html="compiledSelect" ng-model="newNumOfPlayers"></select>
```

I declare my variable at the start of my controller

```
$scope.newNumOfPlayers = 0;
```

And here is where I populate my select string

```
$scope.compiledSelect = "";
      var contentSelectString = "";
      for (i = 1; i <= data[0].noOfPlayersNeeded; i++) { 
          contentSelectString += "<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>";
      }
     $scope.compiledSelect = $sce.trustAsHtml(contentSelectString);
```

but this always logs as 0

```
console.log("new number "+$scope.newNumOfPlayers);
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain your process how it should work so we can suggest a better approach using `ng-options` because without these, you'd have to write a new directive that will watch over your dynamically generated `select` so it will propagate into your model. I'm specifically interested how are `data`, `data[0].noOfPlayersNeeded` and `newNumOfPlayersNeeded` related.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you are using `ng-bind-html` instead of `ng-options`?

Here is a reasonably clean way to do this with just a number input:

First we create a filter that creates an array with numbers equal leading up to your threshold (number of players needed)

```
app.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, min, max) {
    min = parseInt(min); //Make string input int
    max = parseInt(max);
    for (var i=min; i<=max; i++)
      input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
});
```

Next up we use `ng-options` combined with our filter to populate the select

```
<select ng-model="newNumOfPlayers" ng-options="n for n in [] | range:1:noOfPlayersNeeded"></select>
```

Now `newNumberOfPlayers` should be updated correctly and the range filter doesn't pollute your controller and can be used whereever you need it. Please note that `noOfPlayersNeeded` should be in your scope.